# Starting AWS DMS Replication Task in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, terraform, aws-dms

Is there any way to *start* an **AWS Database Migration Service** `full-load-and-cdc` replication task through **Terraform**? Preferably, this would start automatically upon creation of the task.

The AWS DMS console provides an option to "[Start task on create](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_On-PremOracle2Aurora.Steps.CreateTask.html)", and the AWS CLI provides a [`start-replication-task`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/start-replication-task.html) command, but I'm not seeing similar options in the [Terraform resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/). The [`aws_dms_replication_task`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dms_replication_task.html) provides the [`cdc_start_time`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dms_replication_task.html#cdc_start_time) argument, but I think this may apply only to `cdc` tasks. I've tried setting this argument to a number of past/current/future timestamps with my `full-load-and-cdc` replication task, but the task never started (it was merely created and entered the `ready` state).

I'd be glad to log a feature request to Terraform if this feature is not supported, but wanted to check with the community first to see if I was overlooking an existing way to do this today.

(Note: This question has also been logged to the [Terraform Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/Cavx7e8PUJI).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've logged an issue for this feature request:

[Terraform AWS Provider #2083: Support Starting AWS Database Migration Service Replication Task](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2083)